# Getting exception when clicking the back button in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

From my application, i am going to the Blackberry Native Message Application to send mail.
when i am clicking the back button, it is giving `Runtime Exception`.
My code is below:

```
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if( field == m_lfMailId)
    {
        displayEmail();
    }

}

private void displayEmail()
    {
        Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW,"feedback@merucabs.com","",""));
        Address toList[] = new Address[1];

    }
```

Comment: Is there a message to the exception?

Comment: JVM Error 104, Uncaught Runtime Exception. This is the exception showing in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually set the simulator to ignore Error 104 - start fledge with the flag /ignore-error=104. This should not be showing on a real device, you can see some more information in [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JVM-Error-104/td-p/36987). If you click continue on the simulator's white screen, does it continue alright?

Comment: I resolved this problem. Actually i am using label field as hyperlink and in field change method i was doing the particular action. Now i am using navigation Click() method and it is working fine.

Comment: but i dont know, when i was using field change, why it is throwing exception.

Comment: After some years of Blackberry programming I stopped asking why...  :)

Comment: But seriously - it is possibly because you are invoking it directly from the current thread and not in a UiApplication.InvokeLater or InvokeAndWait. You can try it out and see if it also works...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4574/discussion-between-arindam-mukherjee-and-tamar)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code below to your screen and click on back button.

```
public boolean onClose() 
{
      return super.onClose();
}
```